# Implementing full text search with Tridion Query

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I have to implement full-ext search for website based on SDL Tridion WCMS. Any suggestions or an idea  how to implement full text search using Tridion Query?

Answer (score 7):

The SDL Tridion Content Delivery API is designed for retrieval of content based on system or custom metadata and/or taxonomy. The full text is not available via the API for searching. To implement a full text site search on a Tridion site it is normal to use/integrate a separate search engine, such as [Google Site Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) or one of the [Lucene based](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) solutions. The best integrations usually use a [storage extension](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_35CC2F9DCEA34995931E181C165FCC0F) to notify the search indexer when content has changed.

See [How can we integrate Microsoft FAST with SDL Tridion 2011 SP1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014950/how-can-we-integrate-microsoft-fast-with-sdl-tridion-2011-sp1) and [Extending Content Delivery Storage in SDL Tridion 2011](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/extending-content-delivery-storage-sdltridion-2011-1.aspx) for some ideas/examples.

Answer (score 3):

If your site is accessible to a Google bot, Google Site Search is easy.

You might also look to the app server for your full text search (for instance its in a .NET/SQL environment).

If you want an enterprise search platform, check out the open source [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). With Java, .Net and JavaScript APIs and a REST-based server/service, this open source option is worth taking a long look.

Not to go too far off topic, but this helped me visualize when I was answering the same question for the first time: site search means three things. One, a search engine; two, a search schema/index (decide what the beast eats and feed it); three, a search user interface.